# Select data for last X month from table with year and month separated in different coloumns

Tags: sql, select

on my SQL Server I have a table with a lot of data. There are two columns for year (smallint) and month (tinyint).

What is the best and most performed way to separate data for the last X month.

I have declared variables

- @YearFrom
- @YearTo
- @MonthFrom
- @MonthTo

with correct values.  Now I have realised that my WHERE statement doesn't work as expected:

```
WHERE (year >= @yearfrom AND month >= @monthfrom) 
AND (year <= @yearto AND month <= @monthto)
```

Because when selecting the data from the last 12 month, my variables are

- @YearFrom = 2012
- @YearTo = 2013
- @MonthFrom = 9
- @MonthTo = 9

and the SELECT would just give me data from 09 2012/2013

```
WHERE (year >= 2012 AND month >= 9) 
AND (year <= 2013 AND month <= 9)
```

So, actually there are two possiblities to solve the problem:

- First with variable X last month @lastMonth = 12
- or with the 4 helper varibales I have declared (yearfrom, yearto, monthfrom, monthto).

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?!?!?

Thanks for every reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE (year = @yearfrom AND month >= @monthfrom or year > @yearfrom) 
AND (year = @yearto AND month <= @monthto or year < @yearto)
```